# Powershell : Invoke-WebRequest - Jenkins api build trigger

Tags: powershell, jenkins

```
$apit="userid:apitoken"
$serverhost="@host1.com"
$vin="https://${apit}\${serverhost}"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $vin -Method POST
```

error log :

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot bind parameter 'Uri'. Cannot convert value "https://${apit}\${serverhost}" to type "System.Uri". Error: 

"Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed."
At line:5 char:24
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $vin -Method POST
+                        ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: Is that what it is supposed to look like? `https://userid:apitoken\@host1.com` That does not look right.

Comment: this is how we are calling this url in PERL script to trigger the Jenkins build, not sure on how to execute the url using powershell

Comment: it is Jenkins userid, I am trying to do Jenkins build using powershell  command

Comment: If you can post the relevant contents of the Perl script we may be able to help you further. The issue right now is the Uri is not properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$apit="userid:apitoken"
$serverhost="@host1.com"

$vin="https://" + $apit + $serverhost
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $vin -Method POST
```

This syntax for string concatenation is the most readable IMO.  Your curly braces are unnecessary.